# Are money words considered poison words in SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords, content

It seems like in the long distant past, I read that money words like *price*, *sell*, and *buy* were bad for SEO.  When googling for this I cannot seem to find anything other than some very old articles and typically they refer to sexual content or stop words.

I'm thinking along the lines of websites where *price*, *we buy*, *sell* are often used often bordering on key word stuffing.  Assuming we aren't keyword stuffing, do we have anything definitive that indicates that money words in and of themselves can trigger SEO problems?

Comment: NO words are poison words if the words are relevant to your content. Cat can be considered irrelevant if you sell towels.. unless its towels for cats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User may search for price of something, then this word is absolutely valuable. So it depends on content and aim of site. I don't known about will it trigger problems in google, but in another search engine I can't live without word "price". Sites designed to some category of purchases are good searchable with "price", when there are many sites without price and not actually selling, but describe things.

Update: I have tested it as google user, find all above true. I can't find "something" to buy at known/low price in a big city without word price. While searching for pharmacy, for example, by drug name, I can't even find a offline shop on first page without word price. However this behavior changed, for example, when searching for computer parts, fist people find a good shop in good transport connectivity, then use its site(in my region). This sites include price always.

So, its up to your location and things you selling. My advice to include "price" not alone but with description of  product, it will always work.